# How to divide weakly connected graph into "k" weakly connected subgraphs (using e.g. networkx)?

Tags: graphs, directed-graphs

I have a weakly-connected weighted digraph $G$, and I'd like to divide it into $k$ weakly connected subgraphs $G_k$ each with approximate equal total weight $w_{T_k}$ ($w_{T_k}$ = sum of weights of all edges in $G_k$).

I'm not able to find exactly what I'm looking for using `networkx`, so I'm wondering if there's an easy way to do this by combining some of the existing functionality, such as:

`weakly_connected_components`: https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.components.weakly_connected_components.html

But if this method is applied to a graph that is already weakly connected, it just returns the graph $G$ given as input.  Is there an easy way to use this to find $k$ weakly connected subgraphs?  As long as $k\le|E|$, then to me it seems like it should always be possible.

Comment: What are your criteria for the division?  What properties must the subgraphs satisfy?  Are you trying to optimize anything in the choice of the subgraphs?  Could you choose k-1 of them to contain a single vertex and the kth to contain all remaining vertices, or would that be unacceptable?

Comment: Instead of dividing the vertices of the original graph, I had in mind dividing the edges of the original weakly-connected graph into several weakly-connected subgraphs.  As a first pass, I desire to divide the number edges approximately evenly amongst the $k$ subgraphs (starting with a unweighted weakly connected graph $G$). Eventually the goal is to divide weighted edges so that the $k$ subgraphs have approximately equal summed weight (starting with a weighted weakly connected graph $G$).  Does it make sense?

Comment: Perhaps it's already clear, but this means that the subgraphs must be allowed to share vertices but not edges.

Comment: Please don't leave clarifications in the comments.  Instead, [edit] the question so it is self-contained and reads well for someone who encounters this for the first time.  I still don't understand the problem statement.  Telling us about an algorithm you were contemplating for solving the problem is not a substitute for a clear specification of the problem.

Comment: Okay. I'll edit the question, sorry about that.

Comment: What does "divide" mean?  Apparently it doesn't mean that a partition of the vertices; so what does it mean?  Please specify precisely in the question.  You mention in the comments that edges cannot overlap; that needs to be stated in the question.  What are the inputs to the algorithm?  Where do the weights $w_{T_k}$ come from?

Comment: This problem statement is in terms of weak-connectivity and the desired output is expressed in terms of weak-connectivity, so I'm not sure why you are dealing with a directed graph for this problem at all... It seems you can capture the exact same problem with undirected graphs, and asking for a partition into connected graphs

Comment: Also, your problem is clearly NP-hard by subset sum. If you have an instance $[n_1, n_2, \ldots, n_k]$ of subset sum, you can create a disjoint collection of edges with weights $n_i$ and then connect them sufficient 0-weight edges for an instance of your problem.